# how to publish web application in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run ASP.NET C# web application locally???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190217/how-to-run-asp-net-c-web-application-locally)

How to publish web application done on Visual Studio 2010, OS windows-7 and after that how to view it locally?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that either "OneClick" or "Web Deploy" would be it for you. Both should work very smoothly once it is all setup. (I have only used the secod alternative for web services, and it works like a charm).

It is a fairly large topic but I think that this should make a good start for further information: [ASP.NET Deployment Content Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386521.aspx)