# Run (deploy?) ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5 locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am a Web Designer, not a programmer, specially not an ASP.NET MVC programmer.

At my work there are no programmers anymore. The application was developed by a contracted programmer and the contract has finished. I am the person that will reuse his work for this year (it is about a festival that happens every year). My job is to change the CSS with the objective of keeping the functionality and changing the appereance.

Following best practices, I want to "develop" locally on my computer (Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, IIS 7.5 and Visual Studio Professional 2013) and, after the job is approved, put the application online again.

I tried to follow those steps in these questions (and answers):

[How to run ASP.NET C# web application locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190217/how-to-run-asp-net-c-sharp-web-application-locally)

[ASP.NET MVC on IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5)

[ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

I tried this tutorial too, following another answer in another question:

[ASP.NET MVC 4 and IIS7: How to Configure/Run ASP.NET MVC4 web application in IIS 7](http://codingcluster.blogspot.ca/2012/07/aspnet-mvc-4-and-iis7-how-to.html)

But I could not get the thing to work. I do not know how to configure IIS to past the various error messages. Some of them are:

403 forbidden

Configuration Error

```
Line 24:     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 25:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 26:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 27:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
Line 28:     </authentication>
```

In one of the searched answers, Mark Boltuc says to put this on the Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

It did not work either.

**The application is in a server running Windows Server 2008 and the database is in another server (HOSTGATOR) and is using MySQL.**

Could someone, please show me the steps to solve this?

Thank you, very much.

**Edit:**

I cannot put an image...

Well, on IIS Manager, I created another site, outside the Default and stop it. My site is running on IIS.

In the Application Pools I created an application with the same name. It is started, the .NET framework version is now v2.0 but I already tried to put it as v4.0 and it did not work. The manage Pipeline is Integrated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP MVC in IIS 7 results in: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741439/asp-mvc-in-iis-7-results-in-http-error-403-14-forbidden)

Comment: It's not your fault but I think there's just too much pre-requisite knowledge you probably don't have for anyone here to help you get things up and running. I'd ask your manager to get the contractor (or another experienced .NET dev) back for a day to show you the basics.

Comment: I understand. Today I will try to contact the developer to help me out. I do not know how he will react. He is not receiving any money anymore. Here, the resources are scarce... I tried to find some help in the IT sector of the building, but they told me that there is not any developer there that works with ASP.NET, so they could not support me.

Comment: Try to take a look at your application pool, is your framework set correctly?

Comment: User2012384, probabilly not. That's the reason why I am asking. I must be doing something inappropriate. I will edit my question to show, through an image, how my IIS (application pool) is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missing the handler since you using the form authentification

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: DarkVision, thank you for your answer. I tried the following:
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
Did not work: Server Error in '/' Applicatio

Comment: can you comment this lines Line 26:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 27:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
Line 28:     </authentication> and re-run the application see if its working i wonder if they is restriction on your form loggin

Comment: DarkVision. It did not work. This time I still receiving the HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error. But I have just noticed something: There are two Web.config files. The bigger one is in the root of the application, and the other one is in a folder called Views. Do I have to change them all?

Comment: just the root application