# Schedule Run Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, taskscheduler

I have a web application hosted on IIS server. I want to schedule a task to run the application (call routine.aspx) every 1 hour. I do not need to pass any argument or do not need any browser. Just want the application to run every 1 hour. How do I do that? If I use Windows Task Scheduler, how will the "Actions" tab look like?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190217/how-to-run-asp-net-c-sharp-web-application-locally

Comment: This might help...go through this link: [Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

Comment: see this too: [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/features.html)

Answer (score 0):

Timer with a duration of 1 Hour will be sufficient for your requirement. Just follow this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx and try to implement it. You Can invoke your required method or snippet of code that is supposed to run at every one hour..